# Why the strong difference between closures and functions in Rust and how to work around it?

Tags: function, closures, rust

I just ran into a problem with how Rust handles closures.

Let's assume I'm a library author and have written this method

```
fn get(&mut self, handler: fn() -> &str){
    //do something with handler
}
```

Now if a user wants to call this method like this

```
let foo = "str";
server.get(|| -> &str { foo });
```

It won't work because Rust, [according to it's documentation](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/book/closures.html) makes a strong difference between regular functions and closures.

Do I as a library author always have to make such methods accept closures instead of regular functions to not restrict *library users* too much?

Also it seems to me as if closures are the only way to write *anonymous* functions or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, `fn()` types can be automatically "promoted" to `||` types. (A closure with an empty environment, I suppose.) For example, this works:

```
fn get(handler: || -> &str) -> &str {
    handler()
}

fn main() {
    fn handler_fn() -> &str { "handler_fn" }
    let handler_cl = || -> &str "handler_cl";
    println!("{}", get(handler_fn));
    println!("{}", get(handler_cl));
}
```

So if your library function `get` doesn't care whether `handler` is a closure or not, then it seems reasonable to just accept closures for maximum flexibility. But this isn't always possible. For example, if you wanted to execute `handler` in another task, then I believe it must be a `fn` or a `proc` type. (I'm not 100% certain here---I may be missing a detail.)

With regard to anonymous functions, yes, a `||` or a `proc` closure are the only two ways to write anonymous functions.

Comment: ok, it seems closures really are the way to go then. However, that opened the pandoras box for me. You might want to take a look at my next question ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859866/how-to-specify-lifetime-for-optionclosure-in-rust