# How to specify a lifetime for an Option<closure>?

Tags: syntax, rust, lifetime

I'm trying to put a field on a struct that should hold an `Option<closure>`.

However, Rust is yelling at me that I have to specify the lifetime (not that I would have really grokked that yet). I'm trying my best to do so but Rust is never happy with what I come up with. Take a look at my inline comments for the compile errors I got.

```
struct Floor{
    handler: Option<|| ->&str> //this gives: missing lifetime specifier 
    //handler: Option<||: 'a> // this gives: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
}

impl Floor {
    // I guess I need to specify life time here as well 
    // but I can't figure out for the life of me what's the correct syntax
    fn get(&mut self, handler: || -> &str){
        self.handler = Some(handler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This gets a bit trickier.

As a general rule of thumb, whenever you're storing a *borrowed* reference (i.e., an `&` type) in a data structure, then you need to name its lifetime. In this case, you were on the right track by using a `'a`, but that `'a` has to be introduced in the current scope. It's done the same way you introduce type variables. So to define your `Floor` struct:

```
struct Floor<'a> {
    handler: Option<|| -> &'a str>
}
```

But there's another problem here. The closure itself is also a reference with a lifetime, which also must be named. So there are two different lifetimes at play here! Try this:

```
struct Floor<'cl, 'a> {
    handler: Option<||:'cl -> &'a str>
}
```

For your `impl Floor`, you *also* need to introduce these lifetimes into scope:

```
impl<'cl, 'a> Floor<'cl, 'a> {
    fn get(&mut self, handler: ||:'cl -> &'a str){
        self.handler = Some(handler);
    }
}
```

You could technically reduce this down to one lifetime and use `||:'a -> &'a str`, but this implies that the `&str` returned always has the same lifetime as the closure itself, which I think is a bad assumption to make.

Comment: Oh wow, this is totally making my head spin. People are supposed to get used to that craziness? :-S

Comment: @Christoph: If you think this is crazy, try to actually use your `Floor` struct...

Comment: Yep, I already ran into the next trouble. :) Am I doing it wrong? Like not writing idiomatic Rust code?

Comment: @Christoph: I sincerely don't know, but you probably will do better returning `~str` instead of `&str`. I'm guessing that you are declaring a generic handler, and you cannot genericly return a borrowed reference.

Comment: @Christoph It's hard to know if you're writing unidiomatic code without knowing what problem you're trying to solve. But yes, the borrow checker is relentless. But you'll get used to it after some time. :-)

Comment: @Christoph RE: &str. Whether you use `&str` or not depends on your requirements. The easiest is probably to use a `StrBuf` (since `~str` is currently being removed, although `StrBuf` is being renamed to `String` very soon I believe), but this will always require an allocation. For the most flexibility, you can use `MaybeOwned<'a>` as a return type, which lets the client choose whether to allocate or not. libregex uses this approach for string replacement: http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/trait.Replacer.html#tymethod.reg_replace

Comment: @Christoph Here's another way to look at it with traits: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/79520fb3fa9cad508617 --- The lifetime stuff is easier to grasp here, but the client loses the flexibility of writing closures. Whether that's important or not depends on your use case.

Comment: @Christoph, hopefully when [unboxed closures](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/77/) will land, the situation with closures will become much nicer. For example, you will be able to store a heap-boxed closure in a structure, which won't require specifying a lifetime.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Now (seems so) they are implemented, but I still haven't found the proper example of syntax for this case, with using unboxed closures.

Comment: @shaman.sir, you probably want to ask a separate question on that, but in short a type of an owned boxed closure which could be stored in a struct could look like this, for example: `Box<FnMut(int, int) -> String + 'static>`.

Answer (score 4):

Answer for current Rust version `1.x`:

There are two possibilities to get what you want: either an unboxed closure or a boxed one. Unboxed closures are incredibly fast (most of the time, they are inlined), but they add a type parameter to the struct. Boxed closures add a bit freedom here: their type is erased by one level of indirection, which sadly is a bit slower.

My code has some example functions and for that reason it's a bit longer, please excuse that ;)

#### Unboxed Closure

Full code:

```
struct Floor<F>
    where F: for<'a> FnMut() -> &'a str 
{
    handler: Option<F>,
}


impl<F> Floor<F> 
    where F: for<'a> FnMut() -> &'a str
{
    pub fn with_handler(handler: F) -> Self {
        Floor {
            handler: Some(handler),
        }
    }

    pub fn empty() -> Self {
        Floor {
            handler: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn set_handler(&mut self, handler: F) {
        self.handler = Some(handler);
    }

    pub fn do_it(&mut self) {
        if let Some(ref mut h) = self.handler {
            println!("Output: {}", h());
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Floor::with_handler(|| "hi");
    a.do_it();

    let mut b = Floor::empty();
    b.set_handler(|| "cheesecake");
    b.do_it();
}
```

Now this has some typical problems: You can't simply have a `Vec` of multiple `Floor`s and every function using a `Floor` object needs to have type parameter on it's own. Also: if you remove the line `b.set_handler(|| "cheesecake");`, the code won't compile, because the compiler is lacking type information for `b`.

In some cases you won't run into those problems -- in others you'll need another solution.

#### Boxed closures

Full code:

```
type HandlerFun = Box<for<'a> FnMut() -> &'a str>;

struct Floor {
    handler: Option<HandlerFun>,
}

impl Floor {
    pub fn with_handler(handler: HandlerFun) -> Self {
        Floor {
            handler: Some(handler),
        }
    }

    pub fn empty() -> Self {
        Floor {
            handler: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn set_handler(&mut self, handler: HandlerFun) {
        self.handler = Some(handler);
    }

    pub fn do_it(&mut self) {
        if let Some(ref mut h) = self.handler {
            println!("Output: {}", h());
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Floor::with_handler(Box::new(|| "hi"));
    a.do_it();

    let mut b = Floor::empty();
    b.set_handler(Box::new(|| "cheesecake"));
    b.do_it();
}
```

It's a bit slower, because we have a heap allocation for every closure and when calling a boxed closure it's an indirect call most of the time (CPUs don't like indirect calls...).

But the `Floor` struct does not have a type parameter, so you can have a `Vec` of them. You can also remove `b.set_handler(Box::new(|| "cheesecake"));` and it will still work.